# Boot Kali iso from HDD in existing boot menu

Tags: boot, iso-image, grub2, pxe, kali-linux

Currently, we have [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/) as our computer imaging solution. All PCs have PXE boot setup, and FOGs boot menu is showing. 
What I would like to do is to add the Kali iso as a start-up option, which would start-up Kali as if it were a live CD. I hoped it was as simple as adding a reference in the 'default' file of the 'pxelinux.cfg' folder. My default file now looks as follows:

```
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
MENU TITLE FOG Computer Cloning Solution
MENU BACKGROUND fog/bg.png
MENU MASTER PASSWD $1$0123456789
menu color title    1;36;44    #ffffffff #00000000 std
LABEL fog.local
-- cut some text --
LABEL Kali
        kernel fog/kali/memdisk 
            set isofile="fog/kali/kali.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live iso-scan/filename=$isofile noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali
        initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
        MENU Kali
        TEXT HELP
        Kali v 1.0.6
        ENDTEXT
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 30
```

However, this does not work. Anyone has an idea how I could easily add Kali as a boot option? No persistent writing is necessary, it should just be as if it were a liveCD.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for my

```
menuentry "kali_custom" {
    set root=(hd0,4)
    set iso="/iso/kali.iso"
    set bootoptions="findiso=$iso boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali quiet splash"
    search --set -f $iso
    loopback loop (hd0,4)$iso
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz $bootoptions
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

IF NOT try this one

```
menuentry "kali_1" {
    iso="/iso/kali.iso"
    bootoptions="findiso=$iso boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali quiet splash"
    search --set -f $iso
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz $bootoptions
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Have a nice day;

**Edit**
I put it in to the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Where exactly did you put the above code? Its syntax is not recognised by my pxebooter..

Comment: currently have this:
LABEL Kali
kernel fog/kali/memdisk
append iso iso=fog/kali/kali.iso mem=4G boot=live
MENU LABEL Kali
TEXT HELP
Kali 1,0,6
ENDTEXTLABEL Kali

This seems to load the image, but it is stuck at 'READY' after loading. Nothing is booting.